# Adverb Or Preposition

Tags: prépositions, adverbes

I am studying French adverbs but sometimes it is difficult to know if a word is being used as an adverb or a preposition. I often cannot find a sample sentence for an adverb. For example, **environ** can be used as an adverb. However, all the sample sentences I've found use **environ** as a preposition.

> Il y a **environ** 20 étudiants dans cette salle.

Loin is also an adverb but I can only find examples of **loin de** used as a preposition.

> La soirée est **loin d**'être fini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) is a good resource for this kind of questions as it contains many usage examples. It's [available online](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/).

The word *[environ](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/environ)* is in fact an adverb and not a preposition (and there's also an identically-spelled noun). The fragment « environ 20 étudiants » is a complement of the verb *avoir*, and the adverb *environ* is a complement of the noun *étudiants*. One piece of evidence showing that it's an adverb is that it can also be placed after the noun:

> Il y a 20 étudiants environ dans la salle. *(correct and idiomatic but rarer)*

Another piece of evidence is that you can put any preposition before it.

> J'ai fait cours à environ 20 étudiants.
> Cette salle est trop petite pour environ 100 étudiants.

*Environ* as a preposition is rare and dated; it sounds incorrect to my ears. Here is an example by Anatole France (given by the TLF):

> Environ cette époque, à la tombée d'un beau jour d'été, ...

The word *loin* is rather analogous to *far* in English, except that it cannot be an adjective (*éloigné* would be the corresponding adjective). Uses as an adverb are common.

> Qui veut aller loin ménage sa monture.
> *French proverb, literally “He who wants to go far takes care of his mount”.*
>
> Tu vas trop loin.
> *You're going too far. (Like in English, this can be literal but is more common in a figurative sense of overstepping the bounds of proper behavior, exaggerating.)*

Comment: As far as I know, an adverb cannot directly complement a noun, only a verb, an adjective, or an other adverb.

Comment: Sorry, I now realize that the *adverbes de quantité* are quite different from the other adverbs.